# How can I use VBA to get STDEV of the values for different types of objects listed in multiple rows?

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for a way to calculate the sum and standard deviation from different time periods for the same item code (Number). It's very similar to the Subtotal function in excel, however, instead of grouping the numbers, creating a new row and inserting the subtotal in the same column - I would like to automate this function using VBA and place the subtotals in the adjacent column or sheet. I've recorded a macro for the subtotal, however, I need the stdDev in the next column without grouping, or breaking the data on the spreadsheet. I will need this data for other code.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
Sub stdDeviation(RN)

Dim FirstOccurrence As Long
Dim LastOccurrence As Long
Dim i As Integer

RN2 = RN
C = Sheets("CONETRAN").Cells(RN2, 2)
    Do Until Sheets("CONETRAN").Cells(RN2, 2) <> C
   RN2 = RN2 + 1

    Loop
RN2 = RN2 - 1

FirstOccurrence = RN
LastOccurrence = RN2

For i = 1 To LastOccurrence

Sheets("conedetail").Cells(RN, 16).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(Range("J" & FirstOccurrence & ":J" & LastOccurrence))

Next

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have one solid block of data in Row B going from `$B$1:$B44931` and also assuming that all the values in Column B have been sorted you can acheive what you want using the following method:

1. Find row number of first occurrence of item code (Number)

   ```
    Dim FirstOccurrence As Long

    FirstOccurrence = Range("B:B").Find(What:="47-901-049W2", After:=[B1], SearchDirection:=xlNext).Row
   ```
2. Find row number of last occurrence of item code (Number)

   ```
   Dim LastOccurrence As Long

   LastOccurrence = Range("B:B").Find(What:="47-901-049W2", After:=[B1], SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
   ```
3. Perform StDev operation on the range assigned using the first two points and write to whatever cell you like

   ```
   Cells(1, 17).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(Range("J" & FirstOccurrence & ":J" & LastOccurrence))
   ```

You will likely need to nest this all in a loop so that you keep writing below the last calculated StDev, and so that you cycle through all your item codes.

To make your life easier, I suggest adding a new column, copying all the values in column B. Select all the newly copied cells, click on the Data Tab --> Remove Duplicates. Now use this range of cells in a `For Loop` to run your searches.

**UPDATE:**

Ok, so your code is a good attempt but has a few things wrong with it. The two main things are:

1. You need to create a condition handler (`If Statement`) that deals with the very first data point. Since you are starting at "B1" the very first `FirstOccurrence` needs to be B2-1 = B1
2. You need to create a condition handler (`If Statement`) that deals with instances where there is only one data point (ie. when both the starting point and ending point both reference the same row.

Give this code a try:

```
Sub stdDeviation()

Dim FirstOccurrence As Long
Dim LastOccurence As Long
Dim RN As Range
Dim workingRange As Range
Dim UniqueRange As Range
Dim i As Long


Set workingRange = Sheets("conedetail").Range("B1:B49999")
Set UniqueRange = Sheets("conedetail").Range("G1:G5")   'Insert the location of the extra column you created with all unique item codes

i = 1   'This sets up your writing position

'This loops throug all the unique item numbers and retrieves and calculates the necessary data
For Each RN In UniqueRange
    'Need to place a control factor in for the very first set of data
    If RN.Row = 1 Then
        FirstOccurrence = workingRange.Find(What:=RN.Text, After:=[B1], SearchDirection:=xlNext).Row - 1
    Else
        FirstOccurrence = workingRange.Find(What:=RN.Text, After:=[B1], SearchDirection:=xlNext).Row
    End If
    LastOccurence = workingRange.Find(What:=RN.Text, After:=[B1], SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    'Tests to see if only one occurrence, if no calculates stDev normally
    If LastOccurence - FirstOccurrence = 0 Then
        'Insert whatever you want it to do here if there is only one data point
        Sheets("conedetail").Cells(i, 16).Value = 0
    Else
        Sheets("conedetail").Cells(i, 16).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(Range("J" & FirstOccurrence & ":J" & LastOccurence))
    End If
    i = i + 1
Next RN


Set RN = Nothing
Set workingRange = Nothing
Set UniqueRange = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: How would I apply this if there were 10,000 different item numbers? Instead of searching for first and last occurrence of a specific number, I need to do this with multiple numbers in the same block of data. Meaning, the [Number] could not be specific and can change everytime I run my codes to retrieve this data. In other words "if the data in the [Numbers] column(B) are the same, Then calculate the stdDev in column(J).

Comment: Please refer to the last paragraph of my answer. You need to create a new column with all the different item numbers, Sort them, then Remove Duplicates. Now use that data set to run through each unique item number. Instead of hard coding "47-901-049W2" you would assign the cell value and loop through the entire column. Ex: .Find(What:=Cells(x,y).value"

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I've modified the code (see above) to link into my other code. However, I am now getting a runtime error 1004 "Unable to get StDev property of Worksheet Class". Any thoughts to why I'm receiving this error?

Comment: Can you post snippets of your code? What line gives you the error?

Comment: I've posted a snapshot as requested. The code stops on the highlighted line.

Comment: This looks good, but now I'm getting the same run-time error when it reaches a line with only 1 row, where it's trying to calculate the stdev for the same row. The code is not recognizing the If statement "If LastOccurrence - FirstOccurrence =0 Then..." line for some reason. I've tried it a different way and still getting the same result.

Comment: Disregard. The code works fine, if only I spelled LastOccurrence correctly. I left out one r in occurrence. Otherwise, you have been a tremendous help.